# Calculation of an error of a non-linear FSR produced by the connection of the voltmeter

Tags: resistors, sensor, resistance, impedance, fsr

**Background:** I'm studying my master at Computer Science and took a course that requires some understanding in electrical engineering. Unfortunately I have a very basic understanding of electrical engineering concepts.
Having said that, I've encountered the following question on electrical impedance with a pretty straightforward solution:

[image]
[image]

I was basically asked to solve this question once again, but now the dependence between the sensor resistance and the force is not linear but quadratic. Meaning: $$F=R^2$$
Should also be noted that question emphasizes that ranges stay the **same**, meaning for 1g we have 1 MegaOhm and for 1000g we have 1 KiloOhm.

So I've tried to figure out what changes in terms of calculation when force sensor resistance changes but couldn't come up with anything.
Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the resistance changes quadratically, isn't the equation:
R = k.F^2. ?
However this is inconsistent with the 2 end points given (1g == 1 MΩ; 1000 g = 1 kΩ), and in fact inconsistent with resistance *increasing* with force.

However, once you clarify that, you can calculate the sensor's resistance for any applied force. The error is then the fractional difference between that value and the value with 10 MΩ in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe I wasn't clear, probably I misinterpreted the requirement. So basically what I'm being told is that - dependence between the sensor resistance and the force is now not linear but quadratic: F=R^2 and the ranges stay the same. It still doesn't make sense? I don't understand how this affects the calculation of the resistance though..